# error when retrieve checkbox values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

hello every one I have a difficult to retrieve my checkbox values from the database my insertion code like that

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">You are in :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Hr-high"><label>Hr(High)</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Pr-high"><label>Pr(High)</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Fr-high"><label>Fr(High)</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="secretary-high"><label>secretary(High)</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="media-high"><label>media(High)</label><br>
                </br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="gwala-high"    > <label>جوالة الخير(High)</label><br>

                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="mogtm3ia-high"  >   <label>الخدمة المجتمعية(High)</label><br>
                <button type="submit" name="log" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["log"])){
    $formok=TRUE;
    $new_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        if (!empty ($_POST['lgan'])){
             foreach ($_POST['lgan'] as $value){
                $res1 = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `lgan`(`ID1`,`lgan`) 
                  VALUES ('$new_id','$value')");
echo mysqli_error($link); }}}
?>
```

[this is my phpmyadmin database ID1 is an forign key from another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS7Ps.png)

i tried this code to retrive the data but nothing appeard in my page

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include ("../../../connection.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION["username"]) and $_SESSION["id"] !=""){
}else{
header('location:login.php');
}

$select1 = "select lgan from lgan where ID1='".$_GET["id"]."'";
$results1 = mysqli_query($link,$select1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results1);

 print_r ($row); 

?>
            <br>    <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Hr-high"  
<?php if (in_array("Hr-high",$row)) { echo " checked"; }?> ><label>Hr(High)
</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Pr-high"  <?php 
if (in_array("Pr-high",$row)) { echo " checked"; }?> ><label>Pr(High)
</label><br>
                <input name="lgan[]" type="checkbox"  value="Fr-high"  <?php 
if (in_array("Fr-high",$row)) { echo " checked"; }?> ><label>Fr(High)
</label><br>
<?php

?>
```

[that is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqP2F.png)

it shouls the 3 checkboxes be checked !
what should i do ?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: "Nothing appeared" means blank page? Usually that means your code crashed out with an error, so check your error logs.

Comment: Put this at the top of your php and see if there is an output on the page .. `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @tadman  sorry I am a beginner how can I check my error logs?

Comment: @zak its still blank

Comment: First step is to find out where they are, second step is to look at them. The location varies by installation, but usually there's hints in the PHP INI file. If you don't know what's in there you're flying blind, and that's never good.

Comment: that error appeared                                                                                             Warning: include(../../../../connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\phpstorm\xampp\htdocs\admin\high\secretary\lt\test.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../../connection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\phpstorm\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\phpstorm\xampp\htdocs\admin\high\secretary\lt\test.php on line 4

Comment: i fixed the include code  now start to appear but not correct retrieving

Comment: thanks very much it works :)